# How do I set the scope in the Facebook ionic authentication provider?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework, oauth-2.0

I am using the facebook ionic authentication provider; ***where and how do I set my scope to ask the user for consent on the data my ionic app will be retrieving from his or her facebook profile?***

I am using this on the client side

```
$ionicAuth.login('facebook',['public_profile','email,user_friends','user_posts','user_photos','user_videos']).then(function(response){
```

The facebook login screen comes up but after successful authentication, with facebook, the facebook consent page does not come up.

Therefore, the OAuth 2.0 token I get only grants me access to facebook's default access, not to the scope I need.  However, on the server side when FacebookTemplate.java constructs an object with the token I get an exception.

On the server side I am using Facebook `facebook = new FacebookTemplate(token);`

I tried with Apache Cordova but I get the same results.

Comment: Have you tried to revoke permission from the Facebook account you are using ? And login again ?

Comment: How?  What do you mean?

Comment: https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-revoke-facebook-app-permissions/

Answer (score 0):

Try with  [OpenFb Angular JS](http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/04/sociogram-angularjs-ionic-facebook/)

```
    OpenFB.login('email,public_profile,user_friends,user_website,user_work_history,user_about_me,user_education_history,publish_actions,user_posts,user_photos,user_birthday').then(
                    function (token) {
})
```

From that scope person who have some role in app get full access but for any other user you have to take permission from facebook. Go To app section /Review

Comment: I'll try this as soon as I can and I'll let you know how it goes.  thanks!

Comment: Anuj Gupta I tested with OpenFB AngularJS, now it shows consent screen after successfully authenticating with Facebook; however, I am getting some extended permission required issue.  Specifically, user_photos and user_videos access complains about permission required.

Comment: For user_video Go to facebook official site https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/videos/ and for photoes https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/  and check for exact scope for video .For Photo it is "user_photos"